# PHP - Evenly Distribute Teams Into Arrays So That No Combination Repeats

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations, permutation, schedule

I have the following nine teams for an event:

```
array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I')
```

Each match in this event requires three participating teams (ie: A vs B vs C).  Each team needs to play every other team once and only once.

For the above nine teams, there would be four rounds (every team will play two other teams per match and there are eight teams for each team to play - 8 / 2 = 4 rounds) and a total of twelve matches across all four rounds (each round has three matches of three teams each - 4 rounds x 3 matches = 12 total matches).

My expected output format would be:

```
array('A', 'B', 'C')
array('D', 'E', 'F')
array('G', 'H', 'I')
etc...
```

The above would total twelve arrays.

How would you distribute the above nine teams across twelve separate arrays (each array representing a match) so that every team plays every other team once and only once?

Comment: Since there are only `9` teams, why not hardcode those twelve arrays? Because it would take exponential time to compute that golden combination of rounds. So better take it from Internet and paste it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sorts of problems come under design theory. I think in this case what is called the Steiner system S(2,3,9)

123, 456, 789, 147, 258, 369,
159, 267, 348, 168, 249 and 357.

Where I have cut and pasted from http://users.mct.open.ac.uk/mjg47/papers/IntroSteiner.pdf in the hope of avoiding typos.

(The theory is a huge collection of tricks and special cases. I don't know of a general algorithm that always finds an answer and covers every case)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to consider this as a system of constraints. Such a problem can be solved with a constraint solver. This problem is sometimes called the **social golfer problem** (Google will find a lot of references). The mathematical model can look like:

Indices:

```
  t in {A,..,I}  (team)
  r in {round1,..,round4}
  m in {match1,..,match3}
```

Binary variable:

```
x(r,m,t) in {0,1}  (indicates if team t plays in round r, match m)
```

Constraints:

```
sum(m,x(r,m,t)) = 1 for all r,t                    (team plays exactly once in a round)
sum(t,x(r,m,t)) = 3 for all r,m                    (three teams in a match)  
sum((r,m), x(r,m,t1)*x(r,m,t2)) <= 1 for all t1<t2 (teams play once in same match)
```

This can be solved with a constraint solver or a MIQCP (Mixed Integer Quadratically Constrained Programming) solver. (In the latter case add a dummy objective). The last quadratic constraint can be linearized, in which case we can also solve it using a linear MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) solver.

My solution looks like:

```
----     33 VARIABLE x.L  

                        A           B           C           D           E           F           G           H           I

round1.match1                       1                                                           1           1
round1.match2                                   1                                   1                                   1
round1.match3           1                                   1           1
round2.match1           1                                                           1           1
round2.match2                       1                       1                                                           1
round2.match3                                   1                       1                                   1
round3.match1                       1                                   1           1
round3.match2           1                                                                                   1           1
round3.match3                                   1           1                                   1
round4.match1           1           1           1
round4.match2                                               1                       1                       1
round4.match3                                                           1                       1                       1
```